# Nginx stops working suddenly and I can't find the reason

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, web-server

I have a complex problem, that I don't know how to debug. In my prod server i have a nginx compiled from source with page speed. And everything works fine, however sometimes, i can't identify a pattern, nginx stops working, without any error in error log.

```
error_log /usr/local/nginx/localhost-error.log;
```

If I do HTOP i can't find any pid related with nginx, so I need to start manually nginx every time that I have this issue.

```
nohup /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx &
```

Otherwise, nginx works fine. I don't know if is important, but sometimes I receive a brute force attack against basic auth, but I use fail to ban after 3 wrong attempts.

How can I find the reason of this problem?

---

```
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is successful

nginx version: nginx/1.10.1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Need more information

It's hard to say exactly what the problem is without more information. Just gonna throw some thoughts your way. Edit your post with more information and maybe we can figure it out.

## Questions

1. How is nginx being run? Is it being run using a service or using an ad-hoc method?

   - If it's being run by init (upstart, systemd, etc), they (usually?) will log something about the process being restarted. If not, you could look at the init job and add a log print for when it is started / stopped.
2. Is there anything relevant in `/var/log/syslog`?
3. Save the `stdout` / `stderr` from nginx. Something like this. Maybe you'll catch something interesting when it happens again.  `nohup /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx >> /var/log/nginx.out 2>&1 &`
4. Run a script that will log whenever it sees nginx die. You could then use this to correlate it with other events on the system.

   > ```
   > while true; do
   >     NUM_INSTANCES=$(ps -A | grep nginx | wc -l)
   >     if [[ "$NUM_INSTANCES" == 0 ]]; then
   >          echo "$(date) nginx just died" >> /var/log/syslog
   >     fi
   >     sleep 1
   > done
   > ```
   >
   > You could also replace the `echo` with a logger call. I've used a similar script to debug my systems. Just be sure to run this in a script file instead of a shell, so you can kill it by doing `killall <scriptname>.sh`.

Also, some of the info on the nginx debugging page may be helpful. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/debugging/

Comment: You should normally ask questions in comments and only answer once the details are clarified.  This doesn't really answer the question either.

Comment: I felt this was too much info for a comment - what would you suggest instead? I could always delete my answer once we have more information.

Comment: It is and the troubleshooting information is pretty good which is why I didn't flag it, but it still doesn't respect the standard approach of asking clarifications in comments, and your reputation may suffer from it.

Comment: I'll follow that approach in the future. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: not the ideal solution, but i am using monit to restart nginx when it stops working. at least until i can find the reason, and the issue is not occurring all days