# Process crashes without printing any error logs

Tags: linux

I was running a Java app on the server, I allocated 30G out of 36G of RAM to it, it ran for a while and then crashed, I checked the application's log and there was nothing, then I thought it might be the OS that killed the job, so I checked dmesg and there was nothing either. Also checked some other system logs and didn't find anything. So frustrating since I've been dealing with this for days, has anyone have any suggestion about how to debug?

OS is Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux, Java is OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Potentially related / helpful http://serverfault.com/a/793259/265400

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/overview/javavm.html